# Why my java docker graalvm image with spring is not running?

Tags: spring, docker, graalvm

I'm trying to run a small project on fly.io checking about that I noticed this article https://blog.codecentric.de/spring-boot-flyio but after following it and making some fixes like adding

> jar {
> enabled = false
> }

to build gradle and updating the version of java-native-image now I'm getting the following error

> Error: No bin/java and no environment variable JAVA_HOME

How can I debug the problem or fix it?

The command I'm using to build the image is

> pack build registry.fly.io/priceserverspring --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny --buildpack paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image@7.47.0 --env "BP_JVM_VERSION=17" --env "BP_NATIVE_IMAGE=true"

The error shown before is the only message logs show, and trying to inspect the image show nothing

I tried running

> pack build registry.fly.io/priceserverspring --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny --buildpack paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image@7.47.0 --env "BP_JVM_VERSION=17" --env "BP_NATIVE_IMAGE=true" --publish
> Then
> docker run -d  registry.fly.io/priceserverspring
> the only thing that it shows later on is
> Error: No bin/java and no environment variable JAVA_HOME